# How to group by customer_name and count mail_sent?

Tags: r

I'm looking for guidance to solve for a scenario in R where I have a table with the following *columns - customer_name, zip_code, date_applied (date they applied), date_mail_sent (date when there were advertisements mailed to them about the service)*.

I'm looking to get a group count by customer_name and the number of mails sent that resulted in an application from them. Dates mailed within 90 days of each other should be grouped together. Latest of those mails should be within 90 days range of date applied.

Sample dataset:

```
customer_name   zip_code    date_applied    date_mail_sent
aaaa            12345           1/15/2017   4/3/2016
aaaa            12345           1/15/2017   9/15/2016
aaaa            12345           1/15/2017   12/5/2016
aaaa            12345           5/15/2017   4/1/2017
aaaa            12345           5/15/2017   4/15/2017
bbbb            45667           3/3/2017    1/2/2017
bbbb            45667           3/3/2017    2/2/2017
bbbb            45667           3/3/2017    3/2/2017
bbbb            45667           12/15/2017  6/30/2017
bbbb            45667           12/15/2017  7/30/2017
```

Desired result:

```
customer_name   zip_code    date_applied    count_of_mail_sent
aaaa            12345           1/5/2016    2
aaaa            12345           5/15/2016   2
bbbb            45667           3/3/2017    3
bbbb            45667           12/15/2017  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(interval = difftime(date_applied, date_mail_sent, units = "days") <= 90) %>% 
  group_by(customer_name, zip_code, date_applied) %>%
  summarise(count_of_mail_sent = sum(interval))

  customer_name zip_code date_applied count_of_mail_sent
  <fct>            <int> <date>                    <int>
1 aaaa             12345 2017-01-15                    2
2 aaaa             12345 2017-05-15                    2
3 bbbb             45667 2017-03-03                    3
4 bbbb             45667 2017-12-15                    0
```

Or even:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(customer_name, zip_code, date_applied) %>%
  summarise(count_of_mail_sent = sum(difftime(date_applied, date_mail_sent, units = "days") <= 90))
```

Used data:

```
df = read.table(text = "customer_name   zip_code    date_applied    date_mail_sent
aaaa            12345           1/15/2017   4/3/2016
aaaa            12345           1/15/2017   11/28/2016
aaaa            12345           1/15/2017   12/5/2016
aaaa            12345           5/15/2017   4/1/2017
aaaa            12345           5/15/2017   4/15/2017
bbbb            45667           3/3/2017    1/2/2017
bbbb            45667           3/3/2017    2/2/2017
bbbb            45667           3/3/2017    3/2/2017
bbbb            45667           12/15/2017  6/30/2017
bbbb            45667           12/15/2017  7/30/2017", h = T)

df$date_applied <- as.Date(df$date_applied, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
df$date_mail_sent <- as.Date(df$date_mail_sent, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains("date")), mdy) %>%
  mutate(days_prior = (date_applied - date_mail_sent) / ddays(1)) %>%
  count(customer_name, date_applied, wt = days_prior <= 90)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  customer_name date_applied     n
  <chr>         <date>       <int>
1 aaaa          2017-01-15       2
2 aaaa          2017-05-15       2
3 bbbb          2017-03-03       3
4 bbbb          2017-12-15       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Logically, this is same as other solutions posted , convert to date, get the difference between  `date_applied` and `date_mail_sent` and find the number of occurrences where the difference was less than 90 but doing it in base R

```
df[3:4] <- lapply(df[3:4], as.Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df$is_less_than_90 <- as.numeric(df$date_applied - df$date_mail_sent, "days") <= 90

aggregate(is_less_than_90~customer_name + zip_code + date_applied, df, sum)

#  customer_name zip_code date_applied is_less_than_90
#1          aaaa    12345   2017-01-15               2
#2          bbbb    45667   2017-03-03               3
#3          aaaa    12345   2017-05-15               2
#4          bbbb    45667   2017-12-15               0
```